# Why is Excel countif getting a double result?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of points in a forest I studied during fieldwork and associated with each point is a number of trees. Each of these trees was given a number within that point and assigned a species. Over 11,000 trees were counted at over 700 points.

I am trying to count the number of trees of a given species at each point, but I noticed that I was getting twice the expected result at some points, so I simplified the countifs to be a countif, and noticed that for these same points, Excel was double-counting the points. Why might this be?

This is what the first 10 lines of my table looks like:

[image]

When I use the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"08-13")
```

I get 56, which is 2x as much as I expect, 28. If I use Find All for A:A, it returns 28 cells as expected.

I know the format for my point names is unfortunate because of its resemblance to date formats, but I have managed to avoid issues with it thus far and can't see why it would be causing problems at this point.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Please try changing "A:A" to be the range in column A that actually contains data. Does it still return 56?

Comment: @FlexYourData Same result

Comment: What exact steps are you taking when you are doing "Find All"? Please edit your post with details of the exact steps taken and how you are certain that there are only 28 such rows

Comment: @FlexYourData While the Find All is a quick check for me, I know these data very well by now after quite a bit of work with it. I can confirm there are only 28 such rows because I have scrolled through all 11k+ rows and that's all there is.

The only other numbers in that column that resemble "08-13" are 18-13, which I can confirm are not contributing to the error since there are not enough entries under that point to sum to 56.

Comment: Try this: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="08-13"))` do you get the same answer?

Comment: What is the format of the cells in column `A`?

Comment: @ScottCraner this worked!

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad it is formatted as text to avoid it being interpreted as a date

Comment: @DavidFoster COUNTIFS will try to convert any string to a date, so somewhere else you either have the date 8/13/2022 or another string that can be interpreted as that date.

Comment: @ScottCraner I should have suspected that, and yet I didn't. Why doesn't sumproduct act the same? I'd love to mark this as the answer but I can't since it's a comment.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT is a different formula.  It mainly has to do with the fact that the `*IF(s)` formulas use strings as the criteria and has to be able to parse strings.  SUMPRODUCT does not do conversions.  As to marking correct, I really do not have time to write up the answer it properly.  feel free to self answer.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @ScottCraner for the solution, but I thought I'd take a couple of minutes to write out the answer in case anyone ever came across this same issue.

The problem is that because the point numbers are written in a format that can be interpreted by Excel as a date, it was being interpreted as a date. Therefore, despite the cell formatting storing "08-13" as a string and avoiding conversion to a date, invoking `if` statements caused Excel to reconsider the strings as a date.

The solution here is to use `sumproduct` instead, using the format:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="08-13"))
```

in which `--(A:A="08-13")` was the first array, after which other arrays can also be used if `*ifs` is required instead of simply `*if`.

Thanks for looking into this everyone, but especially to @ScottCraner for the fix :)